# Spring Cloud Contract returns "cursor" in the response payload for elements with regex

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

I have a java based service as the provider and a node JS app as the consumer.

I used a stub runner here https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/stub-runner-boot for Node JS to run against the wiremock. But whether it's Node JS, browser or curl as client I get this "cursor" text in place of generated string from regex elements.

This is the contract:

```
request {
    method GET()
    url value(consumer(regex('/v2/accounts/[0-9]+')))
}

response {
    status 200
    headers {
        contentType(applicationJson())
    }
    body (
            "firstName": regex('[a-zA-Z]*'),
            "lastName": regex('[a-zA-Z]*'),
            "kycStatus": regex('FAILED|PASSED|PENDING|ERROR'),
            "address": [
                    "streetAddress" : "3244 jackson street",
                    "city" : "City",
                    "state" : regex('[a-zA-Z]{2}'),
                    "zipcode": regex('^\\d{5}\$')
            ]

    )
}
```

This is the actual response from wiremock:

Response:
HTTP/1.1 200
Content-Type: [application/json]

```
{
"firstName": {
    "cursor": 9
},
"lastName": {
    "cursor": 9
},
"kycStatus": {
    "cursor": 27
},
"address": {
    "streetAddress": "3244 jackson street",
    "city": "City",
    "state": {
        "cursor": 11
    },
    "zipcode": {
        "cursor": 7
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that your cursor values are actually the number of characters in your regex.  So that told me something was definitely wrong.  I've never ran into this before.

I think you need to wrap your regex with value()

```
request {
    method GET()
    url value(consumer(regex('/v2/accounts/[0-9]+')))
}

response {
    status 200
    headers {
        contentType(applicationJson())
    }
    body (
            "firstName": value(producer(regex('[a-zA-Z]*'))),
            "lastName": value(producer(regex('[a-zA-Z]*'))),
            "kycStatus": value(producer(regex('FAILED|PASSED|PENDING|ERROR'))),
            "address": [
                    "streetAddress" : "3244 jackson street",
                    "city" : "City",
                    "state" : value(producer(regex('[a-zA-Z]{2}'))),
                    "zipcode": value(producer(regex('^\\d{5}\$')))
            ]

    )
}
```

Comment: I  tried but I don't  think it mattered. Something is not right.

Comment: Can you show me the new response?  I just started putting regex into my tests. Try changing the consumer() to producer(), since the consumer doesn’t affect the response!

Comment: I tried and gave it the benefit of the doubt and it gave me the response as expected - empty strings. Producer functions only makes sense for the verifier and not the stub runner. Have you even tried this? @marcingrzejszczak, any comments?

Answer (score 1):

I came across another example that affects *request* payloads in the same way, when generating wiremock stubs.

If I do not add at least one "field" to the request body, for example:

```
request{
    // ...
    body (
            value(consumer(regex("[a-zA-Z0-9]+")), producer("derp"))
    )
}
```

the request payload is required to be

```
{
    "cursor" : 12
}
```

as seen by this wiremock stub generated in target/META-INF/.../mappings/myContract.json

```
"bodyPatterns" : [ {
  "equalToJson" : "{\"cursor\":12}",
  "ignoreArrayOrder" : false,
  "ignoreExtraElements" : false
} ]
```

**Solution**

All I needed to do was add at least one field to the request body

```
    body (
            aMadeUpField: value(consumer(regex("[a-zA-Z0-9]+")), producer("derp"))
    )
```

And the regex will now work for that field, as seen by my regenerated wiremock stub

```
"bodyPatterns" : [ {
  "matchesJsonPath" : "$[?(@.['aMadeUpField'] =~ /[a-zA-Z0-9]+/)]"
} ]
```

This is probably why there is a line hidden in the documentation saying only [JSON is supported for the request body](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/2.0.x/multi/multi__contract_dsl.html#:%7E:text=Currently%20only%20JSON%20format%20of%20request%20body%20is%20supported).

**Edit:** Another thing to check is "anyBoolean()" which should be changed to "aBoolean()" and "anInteger()" which should be "anyInteger()" (SCC is i guess really inconsistent with naming...). I double check if they are right in IntelliJ by ctrl + hovering over the groovy methods and making sure they return DslProperty or ClientDslProperty

And, as the other poster said, be sure to wrap any regex() with value() and play around with consumer() and producer() if needed.